# What is the $W$ that comes up in some formulae and equations?

Tags: notation

When I put various questions on Symbolab, it returns the symbol $W$, which I do not recognize and cannot find via looking it up.

For example, $(x^x)+(y^y)=(a^a)$ came up with $a = \ln((x^x)+(y^y))/(W(\ln((x^x)+(y^y)))$. I recognize the $\ln$ but do not recognize the $W$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [Lambert $W$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Comment: Thank you kindly, sometimes notation definitions can be quite difficult to look up.

Comment: @Zoey If this answered your question, you may want to accept it.